# Get width of vertical QHeaderView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I get the actual width of the vertical header in a QHeaderView. In the docs I found only the function sectionSize(). But the docs says: 'Returns the width (or height for vertical headers) of the given logicalIndex.'

So the final question: I am using a QTableView and I want the actual width of the vertial header.

Comment: `table_view->verticalHeader()->width()` ?

Comment: Thank you! It works!